# Undeclared Identifier Compatibility issue - PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to combine a few different indicators together. These indicators are custom built ones of other peoples but I am trying to combine a few of them.

Error is as follows:

[Terminal Errors](https://pastebin.com/8kjFNFG6)

```
// I had to paste this here
```

Code is as follows:

[Full Code Snippet](https://pastebin.com/Mtbpi6JA)

I had formatting issues hence I had to post it on the above website. Please do forgive me for that.

I believe it may be a compatibility issue between the two scripts as the Ultimate Moving Average is older than the SuperTrend in terms of versions, however I am not certain as to how to fix these issues.

I have tried reading the pine-script documentation and these are the last few that I am not certain about how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should always start making them same version before merging them.

Here are the changes you should know in order to fix your issues:

- `period` is now `timeframe.period`
- `tickerid` is now `syminfo.tickerid`
- Any plot style will have the `plot.style_` prefix

[Here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_4.html) is your migration guideline for v4.

Comment: Literally what I was looking for. I honestly looked on their platform but could not find the attached article. Thanks so much!!!